# Can anyone see any errors with this MySQL user log in code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a script where an email and password are sent from an form and passes to an action page where a query is ran. No matter what I enter, it always returns 'You have logged out', can anyone see why?

```
<div id="signinform">

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Please enter your email address and password</legend>

        <form action="account.php" method="POST">
                <label>Email :</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
                <label>Password :</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
                <input class="signbutt" type="submit" value="Log in"/><br />

        </form>

    </fieldset>

</div>
```

action page:

```
<?php

session_start();


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","******","******");
  mysql_select_db("deucalio_photostore", $con);
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }


if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //used because if md5 is used in password itself md5 has is created for blank as well so user can get away with not entering password


    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {

        $query = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE email = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";

        if($query_run = mysql_query( $con, $query, array()))
        {
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($query_num_rows == 0)
            {
                echo 'Invalid username/password combination';
            }

            else if($query_num_rows == 1)
            {
                while($row =     mysql_fetch_array($query_run,mysql_fetch_assoc))
                {

                    $user_name = $row['email'];
                    $userid = $row['userID'];

                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userid;  
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_name;

                }

            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You must supply a username and password';
    }
}
?> 


    <!doctype html>  
    <html lang="en">  
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>My account</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Easy HTML5 Template">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript"  src="script.js"></script>

        </head>

    <body class="home">  

            <div id="header">   <!-- THIS IS THE TOP DIV THAT CONTAINS THE LOGIN, SITE LOGO AND BASKET CONTAINER    -->

            </div>  <!-- END HEADER CONTAINER -->

            <div id="main">
                        <div id="content">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){

                            echo'<p > Hello ' . $user_name. '!</p>' ;}

                            else{

                                    echo 'You have logged out';}
                        ?>

                    </div>  <!-- END CONTENT CONTAINER -->


            </div>  <!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->


            <div id="footer" >


            </div>  <!-- END FOOTER CONTAINER -->

        </body>     

    </html>  
    </html>
```

I have been working on this for two hours, I think it may be the MySQL syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this call `$query_run = mysql_query( $con, $query, array())`. Are you sure about those arguments? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php describes some different arguments.

Comment: I am not sure, I am converting this from code I have doing this using SQLSRV syntax, I don't seem to be doing a good job!

Comment: And your comment here: //used because if md5 is used in password itself md5 has is created for blank as well so user can get away with not entering password  

is not a reason to be putting plain-text password in the database, this is setting you up for disaster.  You should do other checks to make sure that the password meets your requirements (like not being blank) - that does not mean that you shouldn't hash the passwords

Comment: I suggest to do a `VAR_DUMP($row)` and see what you get in there, if the content is there or not. Plus you are doing some `if` statements without `else`, for example `if($query_run = mysql_query( $con, $query, array()))` and row count (what if there are 2 matching? I would suggest a >=1 and not a ==1). and to finish, mysql_query doesn't require the 3rd argument `array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to echo $userid; and see if it outputs anything, because if it doesn't that will answer your question as to why you are always getting "echo 'You have logged out';"

Comment: I have tried echoing $userid and $user_name it echos nothing, so the variables have no value then? I have no idea what is causing this it is driving me insane, thanks for pointing that out with the echo.

Comment: try this '".$variable."' instead of '$variable'. when assigning a php variable in a mysql query, if not then try to see if your'e variables contain anything by printing them out, if they do print the value you expect them to hold then your problem lies in your sql query.

Comment: you only set those variables on a successful login, try echoing your post variables and see what is in that.

Comment: that would mean your query wasn't able to do a search in your DB. i suggest using mysql_query, and mysql_num_rows to determine if there is a successful search in your DB. and if mysql_num_rows is > 0 user exists, else it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on testing, it helped me fix my issue, which was using incorrect MySQL syntax.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session_start()` on every request before using `$_SESSION`. I don't see it anywhere in your "Action page".

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question, please see the edit, I was mixed up when tabbing in. Thanks

Comment: perhaps he has session.autostart set in php.ini?